# Calling a class and then a function in a class in Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like to group a bunch of related code into a class under Fabric, and call the functions defined in that class from the command line.

For example here is some simplified pseudo-code to manage Google Compute Engine servers.

```
class GoogleCloud(Task):
    def __init__(self, zone="us-east-1c"):
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        self.compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
        self.project = "my_project"
        self.zone = zone

    def server_create(self, hostname):
        config = {
           'name': hostname
        }
        instance = self.compute.instances().insert(
            project=self.project,
            zone=self.zone,
            body=config).execute()

    def server_delete(self, hostname):
          return self.compute.instances().delete(
             project=self.project,
             zone=self.zone,
             instance=hostname
             ).execute()
```

What I'd like to be able to do is call both server_create and server_delete from the command line, like so:

```
fab GoogleCloud.server_delete:foobar
```

or even passing variables into both the init, and the function...

```
fab GoogleCloud:us-east1-b.server_create:new_server
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?  It seems like it's useful enough that fabric should support it out of the box, but I can't seem to figure out where it might be documented.

Of course, the real code is far more complicated, with classes for AmazonCloud, and KvmInstance, etc.

Comment: Fabric supports [namespaces](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/tasks.html#namespaces). You can move your task classes to separate submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you:

next to your `fabfile.py` add a `__init__.py` (SUPER important.)

add `GoogleCloud.py`

```
from fabric.api import task, env

env.zone = "us-east-1c"

@task
def zone(zone):
    env.zone = zone

@task
def server_create(hostname):
    print('create %s on %s' % (hostname, env.zone))

@task
def server_delete(hostname):
    print('delete %s on %s' % (hostname, env.zone))
```

then you can run:

```
$ fab GoogleCloud.server_delete:hello
delete hello on us-east-1c

Done.
$ fab GoogleCloud.zone:other GoogleCloud.server_delete:hello
delete hello on other

Done.
```

You can make it a class, but i really dont see the point of it to tell you the truth since each task will have to be its own class. Anyway, let me know. (i kept the same naming you had, i suggest you change it)